# Why can R not find function "getStates"

Tags: r, phylogeny, ape-phylo

I am trying to create a character map and was recommended to use Phylotools and Ape packages in R.

I have installed the packages but when I try to do function `getStates` it comes up with an error message:

```
x<-getStates(nexdata,"tips")
Error in getStates(nexdata, "tips") : could not find function "getStates"
```

I have installed the right packages (so I think) and I am quite stuck. Any help would be really appreciated. If you need me to explain anything in more detail let me know.

Comment: Have you actually loaded the packages with library()?

Comment: once you install a package it isn't immediately available. You need to source it. To do this, try typing `library(Phylotools); library(Ape)` which should be sufficient. there are other ways people source packages. Edit: library, brain not awake

Answer (score 1):

The function `library()` loads and attaches add-on packages. You are using `phytools` and `ape`, so you should have in your code

```
library(phytools)
library(ape)
```

You can read more in the documentation, e.g. at [rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.1/topics/library](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.1/topics/library).